# Rearrange values in CSV file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a CSV file like the one below and create a new CSV file by presenting the information differently. The focus would be the fruits and a list of users that consumed each fruit.

```
Fruit, Name, Status

Apple, John, eaten

Apple, Chris, eaten

Apple, Mike, not eaten

Pineapple, Laura, eaten

Pear, John, not eaten

Pear, Laura, eaten
```

*Expected result should be a CSV file like this*:

```
Fruit, Names

Apple, John; Chris; Mike

Pineapple, Laura

Pear, John; Laura
```

I am reading the CSV file and storing the information in a dictionary where the values are a list. I just can't bring all the names into the same Names field for each fruit. they are either replaced by the last fruit for all rows or all rows have all names. the result should be another CSV file. thank you

Comment: Please add your code to the question, and specify what exactly the problem is (i.e. any error messages or output that is different from what you expect)

Answer (score 0):

While asking questions please do provide code snippets or anything that you have tried, as that is better approach for learning and more people will be willing to help you out. Please do keep this in mind and for now you can refer to the following
snippet to help yourself out.

Make sure you set up attributes like delimeter correctly or you might get unwanted result else modify the given script accordingly.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

input_file = r"C:\Users\kartikey.s\Desktop\input.csv"
output_file = r"C:\Users\kartikey.s\Desktop\output.csv"

fruit_data = defaultdict(list)

with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        fruit = row[0]
        name = row[1]
        status = row[2]
        if status == 'eaten':
            fruit_data[fruit].append(name)

with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Fruit', 'Names']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    for fruit, names in fruit_data.items():
        writer.writerow({fruit,'; '.join(names)})
```